# Could not connect to ftp server android ftp application

Tags: java, android, ftp

I'm trying to build an FTP application in android studio but I cannot seem to get it working. After some debugging I was able to avoid some errors in my code but now I'm getting the following message "Error: could not connect to host 192.168.1.2" when I try to connect to my local ftp server made in Ubuntu( my ftp server works fine when connected from terminal from laptop). The application compiles and installs fine. Below is the code from MainActivity.java

```
public boolean bindService(Intent service, ServiceConnection conn, int flags) {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_button);
    connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                new FTPConnect().execute();
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                b.setMessage("Internet connectivity failure.Try again!");
                b.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

class FTPConnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Connecting...");
        pDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                try {
                    ftpClient.connect(FTPSERVER, PORT);
                    ftpClient.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    System.out.println("status :: " + ftpClient.getStatus());
                    setContentView(R.layout.connected);
                    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();
                    DateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    for (FTPFile file : files) {
                        String details = file.getName();
                        if (file.isDirectory()) {
                            details = "[" + details + "]";
                        }
                        details += "\t\t" + file.getSize();
                        details += "\t\t" + dateFormater.format(file.getTimestamp().getTime());
                        System.out.println(details);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + FTPSERVER);
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

// Check Internet Connection

public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (NetworkInfo anInfo : info) {
                if (anInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Logcat:

07-03 23:43:34.901  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-03 23:43:35.051  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
07-03 23:43:35.051  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
07-03 23:43:35.051  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
07-03 23:43:35.391  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
07-03 23:43:35.391  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13338: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
07-03 23:43:35.391  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
07-03 23:43:35.401  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
07-03 23:43:35.401  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 413: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
07-03 23:43:35.401  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-03 23:43:35.401  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
07-03 23:43:35.401  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 435: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
07-03 23:43:35.401  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-03 23:43:35.511  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
07-03 23:43:35.511  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
07-03 23:43:35.521  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
07-03 23:43:35.521  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_CL3357771_release_AU (CL3357771)
    Build Date: 02/25/13 Mon
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107 +  NOTHING
07-03 23:43:35.551  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-03 23:43:54.211  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 I/AppCompatDelegate﹕ The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
07-03 23:45:45.431  16781-16781/com.example.vagil.ftpclient_1 D/MainActivity﹕ Error: could not connect to host 192.168.1.2

Comment: Do you have the dependencies in your gradle file? The commons-net and commons-net-ftp jars?

Comment: I have added commons-net-1.4.1.jar in libs folder and this import on top of MainActivity.java import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

Comment: Can you post your logcat trace to the question as well?

Comment: my gradle dependencies are these: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-net-1.4.1.jar')
}

Comment: Could it be that I use ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I was using runOnUiThread(new Runnable() to run the connection to the ftp server. Once I've removed it I was able to connect.